# Duplicate if condition checking in for(let x in y)?

Tags: javascript

I see below code. And I just want to check if `item.hasOwnProperty(key)` is not helpful at all? My reason is that because we use `for (let in)`, so we get every key in the object, and we do not need to check if this key is in the object. Am I right?

```
public convertObjectKeyToArray(item) {
                let array = [];
                for (let key in item) {
                    if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        arr.push(key);
                    }
                }
                return array;
            }
```

Comment: every item in the array should have a key so it doesn't need to be checked for

Comment: tl;dr: If you want to avoid odd behavior, keep the check. Alternatively, you could use a `for...of` loop.

Comment: Depends - is the item in the for loop the same as the item that is passed as param or is it a different array?

Comment: **Own properties** are properties that are assigned to each instance of a class/object. **Not own properties** are properties that belong to the prototype chain: they are shared by all instances of the same class/object.

Comment: @Jaya Based on my code, it should be the same.  Item in the for loop the same as the item that is passed as param

Comment: then i would agree with @clearshot66 there - it seems redundant and need not be checked for again